How is the pole frequency calculated in a Type 2 compensator using OTA in TI App Note?
I was reading "Demystifying Type II and Type III Compensators Using Op-Amp and OTA for DC/DC Converters" (link here) and came across equation (23) found on page 7.
It provides an example of how to design an Type II OTA to provide 25dB attenuation and a phase boost of 50 degrees at the corner frequency of 10 kHz. But then provides equation (23) to calculate the pole frequency without any background.

I understand that fc should be at the geometric mean of fp and fz, but I am not sure how this results in equation (23).

@VoltageSpike I've personally derived all other equations in the Application Note. This equation seemingly comes out of nowhere. I've looked at my own notes from studying controls, but still have not progressed towards finding a solution. Perhaps I missed something, but that's also why I made this post.

It's basically the K factor from formula (5) in the link below, just expressed in a different form. I also prefer the form in the document.
https://www.venableinstruments.com/hubfs/The%20K%20Factor%20a%20New%20Mathematical%20Tool%20for%20Stability%20Analysis.pdf

@hana So for type 2 compensators k = sqrt(Fp/Fz) = tan(boost/2+45), but not sure how to get Fc in the equation.

k = fp/fc = fc/fz.

@hana Thank you! So equation (23) and equation (5) are just the same. For anyone looking for an answer in the future, the K factor paper uses the identity of atan(x)+atan(1/x) = pi/2 to get equation 5, but the TI application note uses the identity of atan(x)-atan(y) =atan( (x-y)/(1+xy)) then taking the tangent of both sides and using the quadratic formula (positive root) to get equation equation (23), but they are both equivalent.

I would recommend making it an answer instead of a comment, which might be deleted or hard to see.
